# Overrule cmake macro definition in subproject from parent project?

Tags: cmake

I am using a third-party cmake based project as a git submodule. Lets say we have the following structure:

```
+ my_project/
  - CMakeLists.txt
  + their_project/
    - CMakeLists.txt
    + cmake/
      - foobar.cmake
```

`their_project/CMakeLists.txt` does

```
include(cmake/foobar.cmake)
Foo(42)
```

and inside `cmake/foobar.cmake` we have

```
macro(Foo)
  ...
endmacro()
```

Inside `my_project/CMakeLists.txt` I do, say,

```
macro(Foo)
  ...my definition...
endmacro()
add_subdirectory(their_project)
```

The result of all this is that `their_project` still uses their definition of `Foo` because they redefine it by including `cmake/foobar.cmake`.

What can I do inside my `CMakeLists.txt` file to stop this from happening, so that `their_project` will use *my* macro?

Comment: I'm not aware of CMake functionality that supports this, without modifying the `their_project/cmake/foobar.cmake` macro itself. Using a CMake [`function()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/function.html#command:function) instead of a `macro()` does not help either in this case. My current thought is: you could do something creative with [`configure_file()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html) to overwrite the macro defined in `their_project` before using it...